# Hover mouse over header logo (div id hlogo) on each Stack Exchange site for a brief description

Tags: feature-request, tooltips

It could be quite useful and informative to add a **title** attribute to the the hlogo **div** for each Stack Exchange site that displays a brief description of that particular Stack Exchange site.

**Example**

Upon mouse over of the Super User hlogo div it could say

> For computer enthusiasts and power users

Comment: @Arulkumar title tag is for question titles or the browser's window title. What OP asks for here is known as tooltip, and got its own tag.